# Which server requests resources in a webpage with an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I was actually surprised I could not find this on google but maybe the question is too basic. My question boils down to these 2 examples that unfortunately I don't have the means to test at this moment:

1. Someone gets into Google and changes the front page to an `iframe` with `src="notgoogle.com"` where `notgoogle.com` is owned by some guy who pays minimum on his webhosting services. Does that mean the million hits per second on google.com instantly kills `notgoogle.com`?
2. Let's say there are 3 domains on 3 separate servers, `a.com, b.com, and c.com`. And suppose `a.com/pic.jpg` is a picture of a flower. Then `b.com/index.html` has a title and then `<img src="a.com/pic.jpg">` and then everything works great and you have a picture of a flower. Then, suppose when `c.com/index.html` tries the exact same thing it finds out that for some reason it can't reach `a.com/pic.jpg`. So, if I then use an iframe `<iframe src="b.com/index.html"></iframe>` am I right in thinking that it will show the flower because `b.com/index.html` requests the picture and there's no problem there, and then `c.com` only has to do the rendering?

Sorry if these are kind of long winded, I'm trying to understand how exactly these iframes work relative to what server they're hosted on.

Comment: Browser requests come from clients, not servers.  Your second question makes no sense at all.

Comment: @SLaks One of the problems I'm having is that when I request a resource, like an image, hosted on another site I get a 404 response. However, when I directly access the url, say `a.com/pic.jpg` the picture shows up fine but only 404s on the webpage with the image tags (the console on chrome shows a 404 response and shows the broken image icon). I'd just mirror all the resources I need to the local server but I think there's more than a gig of stuff so I was thinking maybe I'd just use an iframe and display the entire site instead. Any idea on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: That happens when their server checks the `Referer` header.

Comment: @SLaks I think he's saying these are all his sites, but good catch on that anyway.  I would hope folks send a 403 for this, but a 404 is valid too.

Comment: @SLaks So if I'm understand this right it's not showing the picture on `c.com` because it blocks `c.com` from linking to it? In that case it would also not work if I embed an iframe from `b.com` because it would still show `c.com` as the referrer because it injects the html into `c.com` from `b.com` correct?

Comment: No; the referrer is the document that caused the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Someone gets into Google and changes the front page to an iframe with src="notgoogle.com" where notgoogle.com is owned by some guy who pays minimum on his webhosting services. Does that mean the million hits per second on google.com instantly kills notgoogle.com?

No.  The file called `notgoogle.com` relative to the directory of the page that has the frameset on it will be loaded by the browser.

If what you really meant was `http://notgoogle.com`, then all the clients supporting frames will load that frame when they go to the page with the frameset.

> Let's say there are 3 domains on 3 separate servers, a.com, b.com, and c.com. And suppose a.com/pic.jpg is a picture of a flower...

What sort of question is this?  Let me see if I can figure out what you're trying to do.

I think you're confused on what happens with iframes.  Think of it as a web page within a web page.  The browser loads the page within the iframe and basically injects all of its contents into the frame container.  That's all.  It's all client-side.  None of this happens on the server-side at all.

Finally, "`c.com` only has to do the rendering", is completely nonsensical.  A domain doesn't do anything.  If you go to `http://c.com/index.html`, and it has an iframe for `http://b.com/index.html`, then the page from `b.com` will be loaded within the iframe container.

Comment: Yes, I do mean `http://notgoogle.com` and that makes sense. For the second question, and if this is outside the scope of this and should be asked in a separate question tell me, is that I have a page `c.com/index.html` where I'm trying to load `a.com/pic.jpg`. However, for whatever reason, when I do this it returns a `404` response when I look at console. When I go to `b.com/index.html` I see the image fine. If I iframe `b.com/index.html` inside `c.com/index.html`, will I be able to see the picture in `c.com/index.html`? Or are there too many potential problems for this to be answered?

Comment: @Peter It's just not possible to answer you directly because you haven't shown any of your HTML, nor figured out why you're getting a 404.  We don't know where your files are on your servers, but I can tell you if you use a regular URL with `http://` at the front of it and the file opens when you go to it directly in your browser, it will work in an iframe.  iframes have nothing to do with it if you're getting a 404.  You should use your browser's developer tools to investigate this issue.  See what URLs you're really loading.